# Identify Image Pdf's in C# using ItextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have made an application in C# which extract text from PDF using **iTextsharp** but some PDF's contain no text and contain only images.so there is no text extracted from these PDF's.I want to trace those PDF's from thousands of others and want to put a check on these PDF's and to log them.how can i do it? I have searched some similar questions on stack overflow but cant find any appropriate solution.

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(DataBytes);
 Pages = reader.NumberOfPages;


            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));

            reader.Close();
            return output.toString();
```

Comment: There essentially is only one sure way to recognize PDF files which *contain no text* - try to extract their text!

Comment: I agree with @mkl, just run your code on all of the PDFs and log the ones that don't have any text.

Comment: no text extraction from some pdf's does'nt means that it only contain images,there might be some other reason for no text.but i want to log only image containing pdf's